Different answers while calculating probability with two different ways
Eighteen balls are placed at random in seven boxes that are labeled $B_1$, . . . , $B_7$. Find the probability that boxes with labels $B_1$, $B_2$ and $B_3$ all together contain six balls.
Method 1 :
Probability of any ball getting placed in either of $B_1$, $B_2$, $B_3$ is $3/7$.
$X$ = number of balls in boxes $B_1$ , $B_2$ and $B_3$ taken togther ~ $\text{Bin}(18 ,3/7)$.
So the required probability is $(X = 6) = \binom{18}{6}\left(\frac{3}{7}\right)^{6}\left(\frac{4}{7}\right)^{12}$
Method 2:
Let $b_i$ denote the number of balls placed in $B_i$
$b_1 + b_2 + b_3 = 6$
Number of non-negative solutions for this equation = $\binom{8}{2}$
$b_4 + b_5 + b_6 + b_7 = 12$
Number of non-negative solutions for this equation = $\binom{15}{3}$
$b_1 + b_2 + ... + b_{7} = 18$
Number of non-negative solutions for this equation = $\binom{24}{6}$
So, The required probability is : $\frac{\binom{8}{2}\binom{15}{3}}{\binom{24}{6}}$
Which method is correct ?

The first method is correct.  In method 2, your distributions are not equally likely to occur. For instance, there is only one way to place all $18$ balls in the first bin, but there are $\binom{18}{3}\binom{15}{3}\binom{12}{3}\binom{9}{3}\binom{6}{3}\binom{3}{3}$ ways to place three balls in each of the first six bins.

Extending the comment of N. F. Taussig, while Stars and Bars theory is valid for enumerating the number of solutions to a problem, it is not (in general) valid for probability problems.  In probability problems, such a method requires that each distribution be equally likely.  In Stars and Bars problems, that is not the case.
